# Mysql query with keywords

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my query to mysql with php;

```
$keywords = "keywords LIKE'%keyword1%' OR keywords LIKE'%keyword2%' OR keywords LIKE'%keyword3%'";

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.cat = cat.CATID WHERE category = '$catid' and ($keywords) limit 12");
```

What i wanna do is search keywords in keywords row with or statement but my problem is first keyword always full the 12 limit so i am only searching for 1 keyword with this code.

I wanna find maximum 2 results per keyword...Am i going to do it with PHP or is there a way to accomplish this with MYSQL query?

Comment: why dont you change limit 12 to limit 2 ??

Comment: You can write a store procedure in the mysql or you can do it in php by running your function for individula keyword with limit 2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is more compact variant of MaggsWebs solution:

```
$common_query = "SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.cat = cat.CATID 
    WHERE category = '$catid' 
    AND keywords LIKE ";

$keywords = ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3']; // change keywords in one place
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (
    ".$common_query."'%{$keywords[0]}%' LIMIT 2   UNION

    ".$common_query."'%{$keywords[1]}%' LIMIT 2   UNION

    ".$common_query."'%{$keywords[2]}%' LIMIT 2
) as results ";
```

Comment: After putting every SELECT inside () it works. (SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.cat = cat.CATID WHERE category = '$catid' AND keywords LIKE'%keyword3%' LIMIT 2)

Comment: You're right. There was a bug on the respective issue:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70828
Thanks for the hint )

Comment: RomanPerekhrest now there is an another problem,

Think that 1st row in mysql has 5 keywords like 
'keywords1' 'keywords2' 'keywords3' 'keywords4' 'keywords5'
2th row has 3 keywords
'keywords1' 'keywords2' 'keywords3'
Third row has 4 keywords
'keywords1' 'keywords2' 'keywords3' 'keywords4'

When i search  'keywords1' 'keywords2' because of all keywords is in first and second row only same 2 record is found.

Answer (score 2):

What about doing each keyword in a separate query (achieving the max 2 results per keyword), then joing all the results together (using `UNION`) so that you only get 1 set of results.

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.cat = cat.CATID 
    WHERE category = '$catid' 
    AND keywords LIKE'%keyword1%'
    LIMIT 2

    UNION

    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.cat = cat.CATID 
    WHERE category = '$catid' 
    AND keywords LIKE'%keyword2%'
    LIMIT 2

    UNION

    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.cat = cat.CATID 
    WHERE category = '$catid' 
    AND keywords LIKE'%keyword3%'
    LIMIT 2

) as results
```

Programatically, you could do the sub-queries in a 'loop' for any number of keywords, making it able to handle any number of keywords.

NB: `results` is a temporary table alias that needs to exist to store the results, but is not used for anything else.

Comment: After putting every SELECT inside () it works.

(SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.cat = cat.CATID 
    WHERE category = '$catid' 
    AND keywords LIKE'%keyword3%'
    LIMIT 2)